# Convert a nested for loop that increments the integer value of dictionary pair into a list comprehension

Tags: dictionary, for-loop, nested, list-comprehension, python-3.6

Anyway to turn the for loop and its nested for loop into one list comprehension? I did not find this particular type of conversion anywhere.

```
from collections import defaultdict
frequency = defaultdict(int)
for text in texts:
    for token in text:
        frequency[token] +=1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `collections.Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter
frequency = dict(Counter(token for text in texts for token in text))
```

Comment: elegant... didn't think to use Counter.